# Determining the source of error in try - except

Tags: python-3.x

I was wondering if there is way to identify the source of error in a try - except clause. consider the following example:

```
x = 1
y = 2
z = 0
```

if I do something like:

```
result = x / z
```

I know I would get a zero division error, also I know I can catch this error like this:

```
try:
  result = x / z
except ZeroDivisionError:
  print("you divided by zero")
```

Now my question is if I have something like this

```
try:
   result = x / z
   result2 = y / x
except ZeroDivisionError:
   print("you divided by zero")
```

is there a way in python **with out if else condition** that let me know that the error is in "result" so I can deal with it (for example set this variable to a default value).

```
try:
   result = x / z
   result2 = y / x
except ZeroDivisionError:
   print("you divided by zero, dealing with the error...")
   # a way that python letting me know that the error is due to  result variable
   # set result to default value
   result = 10
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get it from exception

```py
try:
   result = x / z
   result2 = y / x
except ZeroDivisionError as ex:
   print(ex.__traceback__.tb_lineno)
   print("you divided by zero, dealing with the error...")
```

`ex.__traceback__.tb_lineno` is line number where exception was raised

Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.TracebackException.lineno

But it is very bad code practice. In your case it is better to check if one of variables is equal 0. It is a lot easier and better in terms of code writing practics

```py
if z == 0:
    result = 10 
else:
    result = x / 10
```

If there is a case when you can't avoid try-except you can just get two try-excepts to be sure where exception wad raised

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I think you misunderstood me, I know all the information you have provided, my question was " is there a way to know the exact variable it self (not the line number)  to do something with that variable without raising an error. the example was just to show what I want ( I know it's a bad coding practice, but it was for the sake of simplicity)
thanks again. @puf